# Openx 2.8.10 Video Add Step by Step in Joomla

Tags: openx, joomla3.0

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.openx.com/docs/2.8/userguide/banners+video+ads) to create a video ad with OpenX. I create it in OpenX plataform. Now, I don´t know what to do to invoke this video in my Joomla website. I download an Open Ad Streamer Plugin for JW Player in this [site](http://www.longtailvideo.com/video-ads/).

To see my video add in my site I need to put some code in my zone with this format:
[image]

Is there any tutorial step by step to put an inline video ad in your own site (Joomla)?  What is the best component for OpenX banners in Joomla?